# Who were the members of Hartnell's _Compañía Extranjera_?

Tags: military, california, mexico

In 1832, William Hartnell convened a posse of fifty immigrants to "help keep the peace" in California (according to "The Lives of William Hartnell" by Dakin). The group was called "La Compañía Extranjera" (The Foreign Company). Who were the fifty members of the *Compañía*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The company members are listed in [Bancroft's *History of California* III:221](https://archive.org/stream/historyofcal03bancroft#page/220/mode/2up) as:

> Wm E. Hartnell, 
>   Thos Coulter, 
>   Juan B. Leandry, 
>   Geo. Kinlock, 
>   J. B. R. Cooper, 
>   José Amesti, 
>   Luis Pombert, 
>   Samuel Mead, 
>   Wm McCarty, 
>   John Thompson, 
>   Jas Cook, 
>   Wm Johnson, 
>   Wm Gralbatch, 
>   Juan D. Bravo, 
>   Timothy Murphy, 
>   Wm Taylor, 
>   James Watson, 
>   John Rainsford, 
>   John Gorman, 
>   Chas Roe, 
>   Henry Bee, 
>   R. S. Barker, 
>   Edward Watson, 
>   John Miles, 
>   Joseph Dixon, 
>   John Roper, 
>   Guy F. Fling, 
>   John Burns, 
>   J. L. Vignes, 
>   D. Douglas, 
>   Nathan Spear, 
>   Santiago Mclvinley, 
>   Estévan Munras, 
>   José Iglesias, 
>   Walter Duckworth, 
>   Thos Raymore, 
>   John Roach, 
>   Thos Doak, 
>   David Littlejohn, 
>   Wm Garner, 
>   Pierre J. Chevrette, 
>   Chas R. Smith, 
>   Wm Webb,
>   Daniel Ferguson